# Add a field from external collection to current object - mongoose virtual

Tags: mongoose, virtual, populate

I have a model named 'Ticket' and its schema is:

```
var TicketItemSchema = new Schema({
     externalId: String,
     price: Number,
     quantity: {
         type: Number,
         default: 1
     },
     comment: {
         type: String,
         default: '',
         trim: true
     }
});
```

I want to create a new field named 'entity' in my 'ticket' object, which should be automatically added and filled with the object from entity collection.

But the catch is: I want to use a unique field other than mongod default 'id'. So 'populate' doesn't work in this case.

As a workaround, in model class of ticket, I tried something like this:

```
var Entity = mongoose.model('Entity').schema;
...
TicketItemSchema.virtual('entity').get(function() {
    Entity.findOne({
         "externalId": this.externalId
    }, function(err, entity) {
         return entity;
    });
 });
```

But it doesn't work. So what are your thoughts about this?

Answer (score 1):

Populate with a custom string or id is not possible. As a [workaround](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2562#issuecomment-185872122), "virtual" option exists.

But virtuals are just [synchronous setters/getters](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1894#issuecomment-114509589) that do not provide the option of asynchronous calls, which is what you are trying to perform in your virtual and it's not working.

Instead, you can define and use [instance method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/methods-statics.html):

```
var Entity = mongoose.model('Entity').schema;
...

TicketItemSchema.methods{
   getEntity : function(cb){
       return Entity.findOne({"externalId": this.externalId }, cb);
   }
}
```

And use it to get ticket's entity:

```
ticket.getEntity(function(err, entity){
   //entity of the ticket object
})
```